# Magento2 event when customer session fully initialised

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-session

Is there an event or a method i can use with a plugin that i can use as soon as the customer session is initialised on each and every request?

I want to check some data on the session at the soonest possible time.

I think controller_action_predispatch is to early.

Answer (score 0):

For this case,you can use event `customer_data_object_login`.

***From this event fire after customer credential is valid and set customer ain session.***

But after **set customer data** in session, at **`Magento\Customer\Model\Session:regenerateId()`** is called and this function reset the session id of a customer session.

**On this function you can use plugin.I guess that is best idea**